# Invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'Shape' error when using std::vector

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, vector, polymorphism

So I have a **Shape** abstract base class.

```
class Shape{
    virtual int getRadius() = 0;
};
```

And a derived class, **Sphere**

```
class Sphere: public Shape {
private:
    int radius;
    int origin = 5;
public:
    Sphere(int radius){
        this->radius = radius;
    }

    int getRadius() {
        return this->radius;
    }
};
```

And after I instantiate a sphere object of radius 2, I push it into a std::vector object. But I get an error when I try to do this:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> shapes;
    Sphere * firstSphere = new Sphere(2);
    shapes.push_back(firstSphere);
    cout << shapes[0]->getRadius() <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In copy constructor 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)':
What I am trying to do is achieve polymorphism because I will have several shape classes derived from the **Shape** ABC and I want to be able to push them into the **shapes** vector container and be able to access them and call their methods.

What am I doing wrong? And what would be the best way to do this?
The main point of this question is also to ask the best way of achieving polymorphism.

Scnerario:
 1. **Shape** ABC
 2. **Sphere** : *Shape*
 3. Other classes derived from Shape

Which container would be efficient and simple for me to store objects (or pointers) of the derived classes of Shape?

Comment: Please copy and paste the full text of the error message.

Comment: the code above looks correct. What are you not telling us?

Comment: The error that your code generates does not actually line up with the title of your post, nor does the code you posted have anything to do with the vector copy constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write `shapes.push_back(firstSphere)`, you are implicitly converting your `Sphere*` to a `shared_ptr<Shape>`. But the constructor you are trying to call on [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) is marked `explicit`:

```
template< class Y > 
explicit shared_ptr( Y* ptr );
```

Hence the error.

There are a number of ways that you can ensure that the constructor is called explicitly:

```
// explicitly calls constructor internally
shapes.emplace_back(firstSphere);

// just explicitly call it yourself
shapes.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Shape>(firstSphere)); 

// just avoid firstSphere altogether
shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Sphere>(2));
```

Comment: Will they always be rvalue refs when passed to push_back?

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek There's an overload for lvalues and an overload for rvalues.

Comment: @Barry, won't it then increment ref counts on an object?

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek No idea what you're asking. In any of the 3 cases, we'd end up with `shapes` having a single `shared_ptr` which will have a ref cnt of 1.

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek, no, why? There is an overload for an rvalue reference, which will simply move from the object.

Comment: @SergeyA I was in doubt if constructors always return xvalues, I was sure about functions.